# Using search cursor with ArcPy and Spyder?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, cursor, spyder

I recently installed ArcGIS 10.3.1 (previously had 10.1 installed) and I am trying to run a script in Spyder 2.7 that has always worked and getting the below error:

```
"Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-95832f8a9f6d>", line 1, in <module>
    perimCur = arcpy.SearchCursor(subwatSubPath + subwatPerimsSub[i])

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 1179, in SearchCursor
    return gp.searchCursor(dataset, where_clause, spatial_reference, fields, sort_fields)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 359, in searchCursor
    self._gp.SearchCursor(*gp_fixargs(args, True)))

RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function."
```

I've tried reinstalling both ArcGIS and Spyder xy, but am still getting the same errors. After looking extensively online, I can't find a solution, although I suspect it may be a path issue. Can anyone help me identify the problem?

I don't know if this is related, but when I import from the spatial analyst module by calling `from arcpy.sa import *` I get a warning that states `unable to detect undefined names`.

Comment: Please include a code snippet so that we know precisely what you have run to see those errors.

Comment: If you print out your SearchCursor input (`subwatSubPath + subwatPerimsSub[i]`), what do you get? Also, if you put the line `print arcpy.Exists (subwatSubPath + subwatPerimsSub[i])` prior, does it print `True` (exists) or `False`?

Comment: My code is:
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env
import arcpy.sa as sa
from arcpy.sa import *
import numpy as np

subwatSubPath =  u'C:\\Users\\Cameron\\Desktop\\pythonWorkspace\\subwat/subwat_sub30/'

subwatPerimsSub = [i for i in os.listdir(subwatSubPath) if i.endswith('shp')]

The subwatPerimSub call returns [u'subPerim1.shp', u'subPerim2.shp'].
If I print arcpy.Exists (subwatSubPath + subwatPerimsSub[i]) it returns "True".

Comment: @help.me, that's not what he meant by "include a code snippet". Please edit your post to include the code and format it as such (highlight the code and hit ctrl+k).

Answer (score 1):

In your comment, you write that `subwatSubPath` is `u'C:\\Users\\Cameron\\Desktop\\pythonWorkspace\\subwat/subwat_sub30/'`. That's an odd-looking file path because of the changing slash directions. I would make them consistent (e.g., all `\\`, or just `\` but prefacing the string with `r` to indicate it's raw and that the escape `\` should be ignored, like `r"c:\foo\bar"`). Consider, also, instead of `subwatSubPath + subwatPerimSub[i]`, doing:

```
mypath = os.path.join(subwatSubPath, subwatPerimSub[i])
```

since this takes care of ensuring your paths make sense for the local OS (Windows here).

Also, while `arcpy.SearchCursor()` should work, it's deprecated, and the new way to get a search cursor is `arcpy.da.SearchCursor(in_table, field_names, {where_clause}, {spatial_reference}, {explode_to_points}, {sql_clause})` - see http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/python/data-access-using-cursors.htm

Comment: Thanks Paulo. My file path is actually r"C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\pythonWorkspace\subwat" + "NCDE_subwats_all_UTM12N.shp".  I wrote it incorrectly in my initial post. It still has changing slash directions, but should be functional. Thanks for your suggestion on how to improve this.

I've read about the arcpy.da.SearchCursor, but my understanding is the old versions still are functional. So, it seems like the problem I'm having wouldn't be caused by either file path or cursor type, right?

Comment: Well, r"C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\pythonWorkspace\subwat" + "NCDE_subwats_all_UTM12N.shp". is missing a slash before the file name :) Instead, you'd need to do 
r"C:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\pythonWorkspace\subwat" + r"\" + r"NCDE_subwats_all_UTM12N.shp". The relatively messiness of having to do that is why I always use os.path.join().
Also, it might be that while changing slash directions are okay for Python, the Arc tools don't ingest them well - hence I recommend staying consistent - that way you can be sure it's not that that's bugging your code.